# SQL "batch file" issue with single quote

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I'm writing a SQL batch script file and for some reason, I'm getting some strange characters for the single quote

> '

Here is an example of what I wrote:

```
 DESC Cost_table;
 INSERT INTO Cost_table VALUES (‘US Mail’,2,20,25,20,2);
 INSERT INTO Cost_table VALUES (‘Fly By Night’,10,100,150,5,10);
```

The result in the code when it runs, looks like this:

[image: SQL Output when I run the script]

Anyone know how to fix this?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are using `‘` not `'` (use a real plain text editor for batch files and SQL scripts not Word or other "intelligent" editors which try to outsmart you)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are **not** single quotes that I see in your queries. Change

```
DESC Cost_table;
INSERT INTO Cost_table VALUES (‘US Mail’,2,20,25,20,2);
INSERT INTO Cost_table VALUES (‘Fly By Night’,10,100,150,5,10);
```

to

```
DESC Cost_table;
INSERT INTO Cost_table VALUES ('US Mail',2,20,25,20,2);
INSERT INTO Cost_table VALUES ('Fly By Night',10,100,150,5,10);
```

This [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark_glyphs) provides information about the different types of quotation marks. The ones you are using are referred to as slanted/curved quotes.

Comment: Just after I typed in the question I noticed that and fixed the problem...  Thanks for the quick response though.  That's what I get for typing it in MS Word first.